# arrays with the same names in different functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I have two arrays named the same thing in two separate functions. I assumed the arrays would be local to each function, but some of the values from the first function are messing up the values in the other function. When I change the name of the array in the second function it works. Seems to go against scope if you ask me.  Why doesn't my first solution work?

**Problem**:
*Have the function LetterCountI(str) take the str parameter being passed and return the first word with the greatest number of repeated letters. For example: "Today, is the greatest day ever!" should return greatest because it has 2 e's (and 2 t's) and it comes before ever which also has 2 e's. If there are no words with repeating letters return -1. Words will be separated by spaces.*

Non working solution:

```
function repeatCount(word) {
    tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<word.length;i++) {
        tmp.push(word.filter(function(value) {return value === word[i]}).length)
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math,tmp);
}

function LetterCountI(str) {
    tmp = [];
    str = str.split(/[^A-Za-z]/).filter(function(value) {return value != "";});
    for (var i = 0;i<str.length;i++) {
        tmp.push(repeatCount(str[i].split("")));
    }
    console.log(tmp);
    return str[tmp.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,tmp))];
}
console.log(LetterCountI("Today, is the greatest day ever!"));
```

Non working solution output:

```
Array [ 2, 1, 2, 1 ] 
"Today"
```

Working solution:

```
function repeatCount(word) {
    tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0;i<word.length;i++) {
        tmp.push(word.filter(function(value) {return value === word[i]}).length)
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math,tmp);
}

function LetterCountI(str) {
    count = [];
    str = str.split(/[^A-Za-z]/).filter(function(value) {return value != "";});
    for (var i = 0;i<str.length;i++) {
        count.push(repeatCount(str[i].split("")));
    }
    console.log(count);
    return str[count.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math,count))];
}
console.log(LetterCountI("Today, is the greatest day ever!"));
```

Working solution output:

```
Array [ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2 ]
"greatest"
```

Comment: OK, so what's your problem if you have a working solution?

Comment: Run your code in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) and at least one of your errors will be immediately obvious.  This is why everyone should use strict mode.

Comment: try to declare array with var tmp = new Array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your tmp arrays are not defined with the var keyword within the functions. Defining variables without the var keyword makes them global scope, so hence one is affecting the other.

To solve this, declare the variables with the var keyword, then they will be local to the function scope as you expect them to be.

Comment: doh!!! *homer simpson voice* Thank you! I don't know how I missed that. This was driving me crazy for 30+ minutes. Can't believe I forgot to type var.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the problem is you are using the variable `tmp` as gloabl variable not as a local variable.

Now when you call `tmp.push(repeatCount(str[i].split("")));` in the for loop, the value of `tmp` is reset to an empty array in `repeatCount`, but since you are using a global variable it will affect the `tmp` variable in `LetterCountI` also - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e5xxbqbu/2/

So the solution is to declare the variables as local using `var tmp` in both the functions

```
function repeatCount(word) {
    var tmp = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        tmp.push(word.filter(function (value) {
            return value === word[i]
        }).length)
    }
    return Math.max.apply(Math, tmp);
}

function LetterCountI(str) {
    var tmp = [];
    str = str.split(/[^A-Za-z]/).filter(function (value) {
        return value != "";
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        tmp.push(repeatCount(str[i].split("")));
    }
    console.log(tmp);
    return str[tmp.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, tmp))];
}
console.log(LetterCountI("Today, is the greatest day ever!"));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e5xxbqbu/)

Comment: Thank you. As a sidenote how do I get fiddle to work? When i click run nothing happens.

Comment: @Rennix it is working... look at the browser console

Comment: Thanks Arun. I always wondered why fiddle didn't work for me.